# recoil: Duplicate atom key - in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recoiljs

I do use recoil in my nextjs application.
But if I run next (in dev or production make no difference) I got this error-message:

> Duplicate atom key "companyData". This is a FATAL ERROR in
> production. But it is safe to ignore this warning if it occurred because of
> hot module replacement.

This is the way I've implemented it:

**/src/stores/CompanyStore.js**:

```js
import { useSetRecoilState, useRecoilValue , atom } from 'recoil';
import config from '../../content/config.yml';

const companyData = atom({
  key: 'companyData',
  default: {...config.company},
});

export const useSetCompanyData = () => useSetRecoilState(companyData);
export const useCompanyData = () => useRecoilValue(companyData);


export default {
  useSetCompanyData,
  useCompanyData,
};
```

I use it like this in some components:

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
...
...

import {useCompanyData} from '../stores/CompanyStore';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const companyData = useCompanyData();
  const { summary: headline, description } = companyData;

return (<div><h2>{headline}</h2><p>{description}</p>)
```

I don't see, why this error-message appears. Might it caused of a bug in nextjs, or did I implement recoil in a wrong way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like a problem with recoil in nextjs when you have state in a separate file:
https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/issues/733

Comment: Yep, sounds like the solution for my question, as I don't see any errors by exporting or building the Page. Thanks *r03*

Answer (score 18):

As of Recoil 0.7.6, add `RECOIL_DUPLICATE_ATOM_KEY_CHECKING_ENABLED=false` to your environment to hide these warnings.

(roeland had the correct [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/issues/733#issuecomment-1278983787), which has since been closed)

Comment: Works for me. Add it to dev mode: `RECOIL_DUPLICATE_ATOM_KEY_CHECKING_ENABLED=false next dev`